# querying of SQL table with dynamic date filter in Azure data factory (Azure synapse analytics)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How to pass datetime parameter to a SQL query in a source of the data flow activity in ADF/synapse analytics?

I am building a synapse analytics pipeline that performs a delta load in a fact table. First, the table is queried with a lookup activity to get the latest LoadDate value. The returned value is then set as a variable and passed as a parameter to a data flow activity.

[image: pipeline1]

I am struggling to get the data flow running properly. I have tried to concatenate the SQL query with the filter value in the 'SetVariable' activity but get 'The store configuration is not defined.' error. Same happens when I pass only converted LoadDate value to the source query in data flow activity:

```
"SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.facts WHERE timestamp > @pipeline().parameters.LastLoadedDate"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many try-and-error attempts, this syntax worked for me:

```
concat("SELECT * FROM dbo.facts WHERE timestamp > CONVERT(datetime2, '" , $LastLoadedDate, "')")
```

the key was to use double quotes to wrap concatenated strings...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this SQL:

```
concat('select top 10 * FROM dbo.facts WHERE timestamp >', $yourParameterName)
```

In data flow, you can't use pipeline expression like this `@pipeline().parameters.LastLoadedDate`, you should use the parameter value in data flow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This way I am getting the same error.
I add datatype conversion syntax in the SetVariable activity, the Data flow activity input looks  good: 
"LastDate": "'convert(datetime2, '2021-04-29 07:19:21.0310000', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn') '"
I concatenate it in with the main query using the syntax you suggested, but it still does not work :(